# Error: 410 Gone: "The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."

Tags: web3js, solana, nft, solana-web3js, candy-machine

I have been trying to execute this script (link below) to get NFT Mint Addresses . Unfortunately I always get this error no matter which candy machine v1 or v2 I use.

https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-nft-mint-addresses

```
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
(node:11240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 410 Gone:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 410, "message":"The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."}, "id": "3bc319ad-c4e0-45a4-b4bf-c1009ce99851" }

    at ClientBrowser.callServer (C:\Users\mlvie\Desktop\ranking projects\test4\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:4819:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11240) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different RPCs will not allow the RPC call `getProgramAccounts` because it is very expensive to the RPC infrastructure

You are running into `410 gone` because whatever RPC you're hitting has removed it